# solving an equation where some unknowns must be integers

Tags: algorithm

Solve for *s*, and *t*<sub>1</sub>…*t*<sub>*n*</sub> that minimizes the following summation:

Σ<sup>*n*</sup><sub>*k* = 1</sub> (1 - min(*s*·*t*<sub>*k*</sub>,*C*<sub>*k*</sub>)/max(*s*·*t*<sub>*k*</sub>,*C*<sub>*k*</sub>)),

where

*C*<sub>1</sub>…*C*<sub>*n*</sub> > 1,
*s* > 0,
*t*<sub>1</sub>…*t*<sub>*n*</sub> ∈ ℤ<sup>+</sup>

---

edit to clarify  to problem description:

"how fast of an algorithm you require." Not super fast (But not multiple seconds). n will be around 5-10 or so.

As far as the actual problem, I have a number of "elements" of different sizes on a "page" and this page needs to be translated to a format in which there is a maximum base size for an element of X, and the base size of an element has to be an integer. However in the new format any element can be scaled up by a single scaling factor set for the page.

So C<sub>1</sub>...C<sub>n</sub> were the sizes of the elements on the original page. t<sub>1</sub>...t<sub>n</sub> are the new integer sizes in the new page format. (And t<sub>1</sub>...t<sub>n</sub> need to be less than X.) The scaling factor for the new page format is s.

---

More:

As far as what I've done previously,  I find the largest element on the original page, and if its smaller than X, I just use the existing element sizes on the new page, but rounding each one to an integer. However, If the largest element on the original page is greater than X, I divide its size by X to get the scaling factor s for the new page, and divide C<sub>1</sub>...C<sub>n</sub> by s to get t<sub>1</sub>...t<sub>n</sub>.  But this results in size discrepancies of something like 1-3% on average for every element on the new page but the largest.  Not really all that noticeable, but I'm a perfectionist.

Comment: Without mentioning some computer language or CAS, this is off topic. The word you need for Googling is 'Diophantine'.

Comment: It is not off topic- are alogirithms tied to some specific computer language - thanks for the reference to diophantine, though.  To others - please don't be presumptious and misguided about labelling something homework when you don't know what you are talking about.

Comment: @Mark, the part: *"when you don't know what you are talking about"* sound a bit like biting the hand that (possibly) feeds you, besides the fact that it's just plain unfriendly.

Comment: FYI to all: this concerns an actual program - I just distilled the problem down to a compact form - is it suddenly legitimate now.

Comment: Personally I think this is a legit question, just that it's missing some information, like what are the limits on `s`, `ti`, `Ci` and `n`, and also how fast of an algorithm you require. Also, posting the initial problem might help, because there might be a simpler solution to it than minimizing this sum. I think you show add more information to your question, and not settle on answers. Only accept answers that actually solve your problem.

Comment: @dmckee -- Eh? How on earth can you construe using maths to avoid code as off-topic? Doing more with less code should be what all programmers aspire to. Are you being paid by the kloc?

Comment: IVlad:
"I think this is a legit question, just that it's missing some information...what are the limits on s, ti, Ci and n, ...how fast of an algorithm you require."

Not super fast. n will be around 5-10 or so. (But not multiple seconds).

As far as the actual problem, I have a number of "elements" of different sizes on a "page" and this page needs to be translated to a format in which there is a maximum base size for an element of x, and the base size of an element has to be an integer. However in the new format any element can be scaled up by a single scaling factor set for the page.

Comment: So the scaling factor for the new format is s.  C1...Cn were the sizes on the original page.  t1...tn are the new integer sizes on the new page.  All add the last tw comments to the OP.

Comment: @walkytalky: I've used that metric for quite some time and it seem to work well. Of course programmers should care about math and algorithms in the abstract, but I rely on the FAQ for this. It says: *" What kind of questions can I ask here? Programming questions, of course!"*, so I use "Will I translate the math into code?" to mark the boundary between *programming questions* and *math questions of interest to programmers*. **@Mark** Nice edit, thanks. The problem is clearly on topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should read on linear programming with [integer unknowns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming#Integer_unknowns) as well.
Even though this is not linear programming it might give you an idea on what to look for.

Also you might head over to https://mathoverflow.net/ to get some help remodelling the problem (you have an optimization problem on an integer domain with discontinuities in goal function and my math is a bit rusty to place it properly; check [combinatorial optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_optimization) as well)

(for the right solution jump to EDIT4 below)
EDIT:
Regarding linearity

Looking for maximum of

Σ<sup>*n*</sup><sub>*k* = 1</sub> (1 - min(*s*·*t*<sub>*k*</sub>,*C*<sub>*k*</sub>)/max(*s*·*t*<sub>*k*</sub>,*C*<sub>*k*</sub>))

<strike>might be the same as looking at the maximum for</strike>

Σ<sup>*n*</sup><sub>*k* = 1</sub> (max(*s*·*t*<sub>*k*</sub>,*C*<sub>*k*</sub>) - min(*s*·*t*<sub>*k*</sub>,*C*<sub>*k*</sub>))

providing that

Σ<sup>*n*</sup><sub>*k* = 1</sub> max(*s*·*t*<sub>*k*</sub>,*C*<sub>*k*</sub>) > 0

(which is always ?true? given your conditions)

And term

Σ<sup>*n*</sup><sub>*k* = 1</sub> (max(*s*·*t*<sub>*k*</sub>,*C*<sub>*k*</sub>) - min(*s*·*t*<sub>*k*</sub>,*C*<sub>*k*</sub>))

can be written as

Σ<sup>*n*</sup><sub>*k* = 1</sub> Abs(*s*·*t*<sub>*k*</sub> - *C*<sub>*k*</sub>)

which, if the question mark above hold gives the following

- maximize s and all *t*<sub>*k*</sub>
- minimize all *C*<sub>*k*</sub>

So all C = 1, and all t and s → ∞ for which your original expression approaches n.

Ok, so originally I was wrong with my suggestion, because I assumed a question would not [degenerate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_%28mathematics%29) into [trivial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_%28mathematics%29) case, which actually it quite obviously does.

EDIT2:
My math is rusty, the procedure above is not correct (first step), but the conclusion/solution seems to validate so I will not correct (it gets a bit complicated)

EDIT3 (*C*<sub>*k*</sub> are constants and other corrections):

Maybe I should clean up the answer, I believe the following reasoning is enough as a solution:

The fact that *C*<sub>*k*</sub> are constant and not equal 1 does not matter. To maximize original expression

Σ<sup>*n*</sup><sub>*k* = 1</sub> (1 - min(*s*·*t*<sub>*k*</sub>,*C*<sub>*k*</sub>)/max(*s*·*t*<sub>*k*</sub>,*C*<sub>*k*</sub>))

you should **minimize**

Σ<sup>*n*</sup><sub>*k* = 1</sub> min(*s*·*t*<sub>*k*</sub>,*C*<sub>*k*</sub>)/max(*s*·*t*<sub>*k*</sub>,*C*<sub>*k*</sub>)

since domain of everything is positive to make this ratio minimal you have to make numerator as small as possible and denominator as big as possible.

The ratio is zero if

- *t*<sub>*k*</sub> is 0 for all k ⇒ min(0, *C*<sub>*k*</sub>)/max(0, *C*<sub>*k*</sub>) = 0/*C*<sub>*k*</sub> = 0

It also approaches zero if

- s approaches zero (similarly as above, only it is the limit that is equal 0)
- s approaches infinity ⇒ min(∞, *C*<sub>*k*</sub>)/max(∞, *C*<sub>*k*</sub>) = *C*<sub>*k*</sub>/∞ = 0
  (the above equalities should have used limit notation...)
- *t*<sub>*k*</sub> approaches infinity for all k

(each condition is enough on its own and represents the solution, when combining them don't let s approach 0 while *t*<sub>*k*</sub> approach infinity or vice versa; in such case it matters which one approaches it faster)

**EDIT4:** (actual solution)
Well basically *all of the above is giving answer to a wrong question*, because I was looking for maximum of the original goal function, not the minimum.

As for minimum it is a bit more interesting, the minimum is reached if each term

min(*s*·*t*<sub>*k*</sub>,*C*<sub>*k*</sub>)/max(*s*·*t*<sub>*k*</sub>,*C*<sub>*k*</sub>) = 1

This is the maximum of this term given the domain of the parameters. If we assume (for now) that *C*<sub>*k*</sub> is integer then the solution can be found for

s = 1
*t*<sub>*k*</sub>=*C*<sub>*k*</sub>

However *C*<sub>*k*</sub> is not integer in general case, so we need to find s for which *C*<sub>*k*</sub>/*s* is integer.

If we can write *C*<sub>*k*</sub> as

*N*<sub>*k*</sub>/*D*<sub>*k*</sub> where N, D ∈ ℤ<sup>+</sup> (in another words if *C*<sub>*k*</sub> is [rational](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_number))

then a solution can be

s = 1/∏<sup>*n*</sup><sub>*k* = 1</sub>*D*<sub>*k*</sub>
*t*<sub>*k*</sub> = *N*<sub>*k*</sub>/*D*<sub>*k*</sub> · ∏<sup>*n*</sup><sub>*k* = 1</sub>*D*<sub>*k*</sub> 
(which is ∈ ℤ<sup>+</sup>)

Note:
Instead of choosing s to be a product of all denominators it could be set to biggest common denominator, and then *t*<sub>*k*</sub> can be calculated appropriately.

Note2:
Plotting diagrams of the functions in question helped me catch my error of misreading the question (realizing that minimum is much more interesting). Also I realized that the functions are continuous (but not smooth, so derivations are discontinuous).

Note3:
The above solution works for rational numbers, but I imagine that irrational numbers would not make the solution useless as decimal or other rational representations of irrational numbers would give an approximate solution proportionally close to real solution as the representation is close to actual value of irrational number.

Comment: The api lp_solve mentioned in the wikipedia article looked promising until I read the following in the documentation: "Also note that both objective function and constraints must be linear equations. This means that no variables can be multiplied with each other." So as you say, what I'm doing is non-linear. Specifically its "Mixed Integer Nonlinear Programming (MINLP)", a term I discovered just now: "[It] refers to mathematical programming with continuous and discrete variables and nonlinearities in the objective function and constraints."

Comment: except in my case only the objective function is nonlinear

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that the original objective formula can be rewritten as summation(abs((s*tk)-ck). "So all C = 1, and all t and s → ∞ for which your original expression approaches n." Its only your conclusion here I believe that is incorrect. C1..Cn are constant. I cannot assume some value for them though. I've edited the OP, btw.

Comment: Also C1...Cn will all be different sizes;

Comment: @Mark, I updated the answer with some corrections and further explained the conclusions.

Comment: @Mark, I think I'll write a new answer - my whole answer is looking for maximum, and in your question you are looking for minimum. :/

Comment: To use a specific example, Here are C1..Cn (where n = 6). 71.998200, 395.611121, 430.776584, 376.772482, 394.355213, 296.394365. There is a maximum size for a tk of 127,so what I do currently is take the largest C which is 430.776584 and divide by 127 to get the scaling factor s = 3.391941. And so if C1 is 430.776584 then t1 is 127. And t1*s yields C1 exactly. But all the other t's when multiplied by s will be off from their corresponding C by some small percentage (small but still noticeable). But anyway, can you put your solution in the above context.

Comment: But at any rate, I think I may have it now - I had misread the operator precedence of the expression Nk/Dk * 1Dk.  But if you want to give an answer to the above that might be helpful.

Comment: The thing about rational numbers concerned me for a moment (since you brought it up), but then I realized any limited precision number is rational.

Comment: Still thinking out loud, using my example above, I think I see some problems:
You would have 430776584/1000000,395611121/1000000 [etc.] for C1..Cn. and the largest common denominator is 1000000 but that leaves t's that are much too large.  I augmented the OP yesterday to note that there is a maximum size for each t.  But I have to get some sleep and will come back to this later.  Thanks.

Comment: @Mark, thinking out loud: well the above solution finds the perfect set of integers. If you need to scale them down to acceptable domain you should divide them with some number. Finding the biggest common denominator on the solution (and not in the middle of the process) would be give minimal integers that are still a perfect solution. If that is still not within desired range you will have to live with some discrepancy. Can you edit the question again and explain the goal function (explain it in terms of element sizes and page size, etc...)

Answer (score 2):

Please use Maple, Mathcad or Sage for that. Here is a list of software, that can help you with it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_computer_algebra_systems

Comment: What are you saying - I need to purchase some software product - that's not what I had in mind.

Comment: @Mark, no. What FractalizeR suggests is to use a CAS for this. If you'd taken the time to actually click (or read) the link s/he posted, you would have noticed that there are many free products available. It may not be the answer you're looking for, but that doesn't mean it's a perfectly legit answer.

Comment: Just to be clear, I don't have an isolated math problem I'm trying to solve (for homework or otherwise). I was looking to write code to solve the above, if these are API's or similar then of course that would work. Was hoping someone would give a brief verbal overview of the solution. AakashM did mention Diophantine equations, after of course inexplicably slamming me for posting something off-topic, so I will at least check into Diophantine equations in a moment.

Comment: But anyway, diopantine, CAS - probably enough to get me going here, so thanks to all.

Answer (score 1):

I think that unreason gave the correct answer. You need to read a book about "Nonlinear Integer Programming". I don't have a good book to recommend you, but you can probably find something by going to the library.

I don't think that lp_solve is not good enough for you, because you cannot rewrite your problem in to a mixed integer Integer linear Programming problem (MILP). Maple and Mathcad is not a good idea, because you are not looking for symbolic algebra package.

My guess us that the book will tell you to do branch and bound. Here is a schematic description:

1) Start out solving a generalized problem where t_k are all real prsitime numbers

minimize  Σnk = 1 (1 - min(s·tk,Ck)/max(s·tk,Ck)),
under the constrain that  s > 0, t1…tn ∈ R+

.You can use a generalized Newtons method to do this. Matlab and scipy provide generalized solvers this out of the box, but be careful because your function may have several local minima.

2) Once you have found this solution, you can do a branch ing step. Choose a variables t_k and an integer number a_k, and solve the following two problems independently

Problem 1
minimize  Σnk = 1 (1 - min(s·tk,Ck)/max(s·tk,Ck)),
under the constrain that  s > 0, t1…tn ∈ R+and t_k <= a_k

Problem 2
minimize  Σnk = 1 (1 - min(s·tk,Ck)/max(s·tk,Ck)),
under the constrain that  s > 0, t1…tn ∈ R+ and t_k >= a_k

3) Keep doing branching steps until you have split your problem in to a set of sub-problems that each have an integer solution. Then you can compare these integer solutions and choose the best one.

As you probably have guessed this description is somewhat schematic. You need good branching rules to branch the correct way, and you need good bounding rules to avoid following branches that arent promising.

Comment: "branch and bound" is a term I keep on encountering as well so thanks

Comment: actually my solution was completely wrong, but I think it might be right now.

Comment: Unreasons fourth solution looks correct. That was a nice trick. In the special case where all the numbers C_k are decimal numbers with n decimals then he gets s=10^-n and  t_k=C_k*10^n.